# Pulling a field from a Foreign Key into table

Tags: mysql

I'm having a bit of a brain fart here.  I have a MySQL database with vehicle information.  In it there is a table Vehicles, with a Foreign Key for VehicleMake and VehicleModel.  I've decided to remove the Model FK and just have the Vehicle Model as a varchar field in the Vehicle Table. Now I'm trying to figure out how to pull the models for the existing entries in the table.

```
Table 'Vehicle' (id, vehicleMake, vehicleModel, model)
Table 'VehicleModels' (id, modelName)
```

So basically I'm trying to figure out a query that will pull the data from VehicleModels.modelName into Vehicle.model for each row in my Vehicles table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the update statement you would want to use:

```
UPDATE Vehicle, VehicleModel
SET Vehicle.VehicleModel = VehicleModel.modelName
WHERE Vehicle.model = VehicleModel.id
```

After this, you would also want to remove the FK constraint from `Vehicle(model) on VehicleModel(id)` once your code is providing the application `vehicleModel` data instead of `model` information.

```
ALTER TABLE Vehicle DROP FOREIGN KEY FK_Vehicle_model_VehicleModel_id;
```

This would be how I name the foreign key, your name may vary.

Comment: Amazing.  That's precisely what I was trying to figure out.  I forgot to add the VehicleModel table to the update clause.  Thanks!